# Change sim preference to call particular person in Dual sim

Tags: settings, calls, factory-reset, default-applications, direct-call

I recently changed the second sim and I want that **second sim** to call for the particular person by default, previously I have set the **first sim** to do that action,

Now I want to set those **settings to changed** or at least to be *set to default,like asking every time which sim to call,*

I **cleared data** in both phone and dialer app in *settings of app management,* but still nothing happened, the set default button is greyed out on both apps

Does any one know how to change the **sim preference setting**s to call a particular person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by myself at last,

when you call that person there will be a change sim option in the top right hand screen, by choosing that we can change the sim preference and also the next time we call that person phone will ask for which sim to call.

Answer (score 1):

Go to contacts -> select the contact which you want to change the preference -> deep press on the number -> select clear calling sim.

Now you will be able to make calls normally with the sim card you wanted.